# Reactjs adding javascript code for all components except for one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tawk.to

I got the following chat widget code from Tawk:-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {},
        Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
      (function () {
        var s1 = document.createElement("script"),
          s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s1.async = true;
        s1.src = "https://embed.tawk.to/555555/default";
        s1.charset = "UTF-8";
        s1.setAttribute("crossorigin", "*");
        s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
      })();
    </script>
```

And this is my index.js component code content :-

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "bootstrap-v4-rtl/dist/js/bootstrap.js";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import BookRead from "./pages/BookRead";


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
  
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/view/:id/:section/:part" component={BookRead} />
          <Route component={App} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>

  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App component content :-

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import NewBook from "./pages/NewBook";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="content">
      <Helmet>
        <title>Book Website</title>
      </Helmet>
      <Header />
      <NavBar  />
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/create-new" component={NewBook} />
        <Route path="/account" component={Account} />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How can I enable the chat widget to be shown at `App` component and all of its child components but not to be displayed in `BookRead` component?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper around the Routes where you want to display the chat.

Try this:

```js
function ChatEnabledRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) => (
        <MyChatComponent>
          {children}
        </MyChatComponent>
      )
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Now all you have to do is create your MyChatComponent, in which you can initiate your chat widget. In your Router, use ChatEnabledRoute whenever you want to create a route in which you want to use your chat widget.

By doing so, you won't have to re-render your whole app every time you navigate through you app.